# React: prevent useContext from re-rendering the whole app or share data between components without re-rendering all of them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, intersection-observer

I have a simple app with a `Header.tsx` component that is supposed to be available to all pages and a `Home.tsx` in which the most of the content will be.

`Home.tsx` hosts a `intersectionObserver` that sends data with `useContext` hook (called `homeLinks`) to `Header.tsx` trough `App.tsx`, so I can update the navigation with class of the currently intersected section. The problem here: anytime the observer updates the context, the whole DOM re-renders, and since Home will hold the brunt of the application that can't be the optimal solution. Could someone explain to me how to achieve this the correct way?

Could I somehow sends refs from Home to Header and set up the observer there?

[CodeSandbox demo is available here](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/9p6fyv?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcontexts%2FhomeLinks.tsx&embed=1)

App

```
import homeLinks from "./contexts/homeLinks";


function App() {
  const [homePart, setHomePart] = useState<string>(""); //Home part which is observed, setting function
  console.log("App is rendered");

  return (
    <>
      <homeLinks.Provider value={{ homePart, setHomePart }}>
        <Header /> {/* Outside router, meant to be shared with other pages  */}
        <Home /> {/* Will be in react router */}
      </homeLinks.Provider>
    </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Home

```
import homeLinks from "../contexts/homeLinks";

export const Home = () => {
  const homeParts = useRef(new Array());
  const { setHomePart } = useContext(homeLinks);

  useEffect(() => {
    const menuObserver = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => {
        const entry = entries[0];
        if (entry.isIntersecting)
          setHomePart(
            entry.target.getAttribute("id")
              ? entry.target.getAttribute("id")!
              : "ntn here",
          );
      },
      { rootMargin: "-40% 0px -50% 0px" },
    );

    homeParts.current.map((part) => {
      menuObserver.observe(part!);
    });
  }, []);

  console.log("Home is rendered");

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="hero"
        id="home"
        ref={(element) => homeParts.current.push(element)}
      >
        <section>
          <div className="depth"></div>
          <div className="heroContent">
              <h1>This is Home</h1>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
      <div
        id="projects"
        style={{ height: "100vh", backgroundColor: "gray" }}
        ref={(element) => homeParts.current.push(element)}
      >
        This is Projects
      </div>

      <div
        id="contact"
        style={{ height: "100vh", backgroundColor: "cadetblue" }}
        ref={(element) => homeParts.current.push(element)}
      >
        This is contact
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Header

```
import linkSection from "../contexts/homeLinks";

function Header() {
  const lastHash = useRef("");

  const { homePart } = useContext(linkSection);
  const homeLinks = [
    { href: "home", title: "Home" },
    { href: "projects", title: "Projects" },
    { href: "contact", title: "Contact" },
  ];

  return (
    <header>
      <div>
        <a href="/">Menu</a>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          {homeLinks.map((homeLink) => (
            <li key={homeLink.href}>
              <a
                href={"/#" + homeLink.href}
                className={homePart == homeLink.href ? "active" : ""}
              >
                {homeLink.title}
              </a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

Context

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const homeLinks = createContext({
  homePart: "",
  setHomePart: (part: string) => {},
});

export default homeLinks;
```

Full code is also available in https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/9p6fyv?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcontexts%2FhomeLinks.tsx&embed=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever the `IntersectionObserver` detects an intersection, it sets the state in `App`, and `App`, and all it's children are re-rendered:

```
function App() {
  // re-renders App and all children
  const [homePart, setHomePart] = useState<string>("");
  console.log("App is rendered");

  return (
    <>
      <homeLinks.Provider value={{ homePart, setHomePart }}>
        <Header /> {/* Outside router, meant to be shared with other pages  */}
        <Home /> {/* Will be in react router */}
      </homeLinks.Provider>
    </>
  );
}
```

Instead the context should be a funnel to register to intersection events, without holding a state of it's own. If a component needs to set a state (and trigger a re-render) it should listen to an event, and set it's own state.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/in-tzw36v?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls82sh7q00083b6k6aihsj6f%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls82sh7q00033b6k2k5u5tl4%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls82sh7q00053b6kxezyg4sk%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls82sh7q00073b6k0fcuvdyo%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cls82sh7q00033b6k2k5u5tl4%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls82sh7q00023b6k96lw0uey%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A11%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A5%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A11%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A5%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fcomponents%252FHeader.jsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls82sh7q00033b6k2k5u5tl4%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cls82sh7q00023b6k96lw0uey%2522%257D%252C%2522cls82sh7q00073b6k0fcuvdyo%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls82sh7q00073b6k0fcuvdyo%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls82sh7q00063b6kjbjum04r%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cls82sh7q00063b6kjbjum04r%2522%257D%252C%2522cls82sh7q00053b6kxezyg4sk%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls82sh7q00043b6k6ki1162n%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cls82sh7q00053b6kxezyg4sk%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cls82sh7q00043b6k6ki1162n%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

### The `homeLink` context

The context exports 2 hooks:

1. `useRegisterListener` - accepts a function to register as listener.
2. `useObserve` - returns an `observe` function that can be used as a function ref to observe a DOM elements.

The context also exports `HomeLinksProvider` the initiates the `IntersectionObserver`, and the `listeners` Set. It supplies the context consumer with all relevant functions to add/remove listener, and observe DOM elements. The provider handles all cleanups in case of unmount.

It also waits for the observer to be ready before rendering the wrapped children.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useState,
  useRef,
  useEffect,
  useMemo,
} from "react";

export type Listener = (id: string) => void;

const HomeLinks = createContext({
  observe: (instance: HTMLElement | null) => {},
  addListener: (listener: Listener) => {},
  removeListener: (listener: Listener) => {},
});

// register listeners to intersection events
export const useRegisterListener = (listener: Listener) => {
  const { addListener, removeListener } = useContext(HomeLinks);

  useEffect(() => {
    addListener(listener);

    return () => {
      removeListener(listener);
    };
  }, [addListener, removeListener, listener]);
};

// returns a ref function to observe DOM elements
export const useObserve = () => {
  const { observe } = useContext(HomeLinks);

  return observe;
};

// The provider initiates the IntersectionObserver,
// and calls listeners when elements are visible.
// It also disconnects the observer and clears the listeners Set.
export const HomeLinksProvider = ({ children }) => {
  // delay rendering children until context is ready
  const [ready, setReady] = useState(false);
  const menuObserver = useRef<IntersectionObserver>();
  const listners = useRef<Set<Listener>>();

  useEffect(() => {
    listners.current = new Set(); // initiate the listeners Set
    // create a new observer
    menuObserver.current = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => {
        const entry = entries[0];
        const id = entry.target.getAttribute("id") ?? "ntn here";

        if (entry.isIntersecting)
          listners.current?.forEach((listener) => listener(id));
      },
      { rootMargin: "-40% 0px -50% 0px" },
    );

    setReady(true); // allow rendering children when context is ready

    return () => {
      // cleannup
      menuObserver.current?.disconnect();
      listners.current?.clear();
    };
  }, []);

  const contextValue = useMemo(
    () => ({
      // obsere DOM elements
      observe: (instance: HTMLElement | null) => {
        if (instance) menuObserver.current?.observe(instance);
      },
      // register listeners to Listeners Set
      addListener: (listener: Listener) => {
        listners.current?.add(listener);
      },
      // remove listeners from Listeners Set
      removeListener: (listener: Listener) => {
        listners.current?.delete(listener);
      },
    }),
    [],
  );

  // render children when context is ready
  return (
    <HomeLinks.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {ready ? children : null}
    </HomeLinks.Provider>
  );
};
```

---

### Usage:

App:

```
function App() {
  console.log("App is rendered");

  return (
    <>
      <HomeLinksProvider>
        <Header /> {/* Outside router, meant to be shared with other pages  */}
        <Home /> {/* Will be in react router */}
      </HomeLinksProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

Home:

```
export const Home = () => {
  const observe = useObserve();

  console.log("Home is rendered");

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className="hero"
        id="home"
        ref={observe}
      >
        <section style={{ height: "100vh", backgroundColor: "palevioletred" }}>
          <div className="depth"></div>
          <div className="heroContent">
            <main>
              <h1>This is Home</h1>
            </main>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
      <div
        id="projects"
        style={{ height: "100vh", backgroundColor: "gray" }}
        ref={observe}
      >
        This is Projects
      </div>

      <div
        id="contact"
        style={{ height: "100vh", backgroundColor: "cadetblue" }}
        ref={observe}
      >
        This is contact
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Header:

```
const homeLinks = [
  { href: "home", title: "Home" },
  { href: "projects", title: "Projects" },
  { href: "contact", title: "Contact" },
];

function Header() {
  const [homePart, setHomePart] = useState('home');

  useRegisterListener(setHomePart);

  return (
    <header>
      <div>
        <a href="/">Menu</a>
      </div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          {homeLinks.map((homeLink) => (
            <li key={homeLink.href}>
              <a
                href={"/#" + homeLink.href}
                className={homePart == homeLink.href ? "active" : ""}
              >
                {homeLink.title}
              </a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}
```